# Trying to print from a wordpress page

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I'm trying to make a wordpress page that grabs some dynamic content and puts in on a page that is ready for someone to easily print. There are two things that are getting in the way and some help would be great.

1. after pressing print initially in chrome the page looks a mess - overzoomed so it is incomprehensible. If i dial "scale" back to 60 it looks pretty much like the webpage. I've tried setting @media print scale to .6 but that seems to just shrink the messy view into the middle of the page. Any ideas?

[initial messy zoom at 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr6jJ.png)

[if i take the zoom down to 60% perfect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEzyI.png)

2. some text on the page insists that it prints in black. no amount of alteration on the site will change that. it appears white on the web, prints in black. Any ideas?

thanks.
nick

Comment: We need some code to be able to replicate the issue you're having.

Comment: Apologies, this is the a test page in question http://www.makeasmilelottery.org.uk/pdf3/

i dont have any code to paste because its just visual composer and it displays the above behavior when some simple content is added....i was just wondering if there is an overarching method to alter a "print" command.

Comment: Those screenshots look like it's from responsive styling, not anything to do with printing. If I go to to that link and try to print from Chrome, I get something that looks completely different. Either way, you'll likely end up using the `@media` tag. It's just down to whether you need if for `print` or `max-width` / `min-width`. Without more info, I'm not sure anyone's gonna be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Some text on the page insists that it prints in black, no amount of alteration on the site will change that. It appears white on the web, prints in black. Any ideas?

When printing, the Chrome browser applies its own styling to the page. On your page, the text is changing from white to a dark grey because Chrome is removing the blue element behind it. Without the blue element behind the white text, it'd just be white text on a white background, so Chrome has gone ahead and 'fixed' that for you so that it's readable.

If you're looking at the print settings in Chrome, you'll see a '**More Settings**' option. If you open that, you'll see that Chrome has given the user the option to remove the **background graphics** as seen below.

[image: Chrome Print Settings]

By default, this button is unchecked in Chrome. This is a very intentional feature of Chrome that allows users to save ink when printing from the web. Browsers can do whatever they want when printing, so some things may simply be out of your control.

You can change the styling for the print page by using the [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) CSS query. You still need to keep in mind [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) when using the `@media` query. If Chrome is ignoring one or more of your attributes, you can try using `!important` with whatever you're trying to change.

### Example

```
@media print {
  .my-class {
    color: blue;
  }
  #my-id {
    color: green;
  }
  .stubborn-div {
    color: red !important;
  }
}
```

You could also try this:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

When set to `exact`, the background colors and images of the element to which this rule is applied are always printed, user's print settings are overridden. Note that support is extremely limited to what browsers can & will use it. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust).

> After pressing print initially in chrome the page looks a mess -
>   overzoomed so it is incomprehensible. If I dial "scale" back to 60 it
>   looks pretty much like the webpage. I've tried setting @media print
>   scale to .6 but that seems to just shrink the messy view into the
>   middle of the page. Any ideas?

I've looked at your code enough that I really think it just comes down to you figuring out your responsive styling, and adding the necessary CSS to the `@media` query.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to be sure about anything because you haven't posted a stitch of code. Have you tried setting

`body{ height:100vh; width:100vw; }`

?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that there are "print styles"? I.e. you use the media query `@media print { ... }` in your CSS and there write CSS rules for everything that should be different in the printout.

You can for example change font sizes for classes, tags, or the whole `body`, you can change (text) colors, and you can even hide stuff in the printout, like menu bars and sidebars, by using `display: none` for these elements in the print styles.